# HttpClient+SSL from Glassfish

Tags: java, ssl, glassfish, httpclient, htmlunit

I'm trying to download a simple page from an SSL secured webpage. I'm using HtmlUnit for that task (which wraps around HttpClient).

The webpage I'm trying to download has a proper certificate signed by Verisign and Verisign certificate is present in `cacerts` file (it was there in first place but I even reimported whole certiciate chain there).

My application runs perfectly as stand-alone application using the same JVM that is used by Glassfish. However if I deploy it to glassfish I'm getting a classic certificate problem exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated,
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:597)
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:133)
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1405)
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1324)
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:303)
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:385)
```

I've already tried disabling security manager in glassfish and that did not help.

What can be the cause of this weird behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought GlassFish used it's own magical keystore:

http://metro.java.net/guide/Configuring_Keystores_and_Truststores.html

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If this is test or temporary code and you don't care to validate the certificate, try [accepting all certs and host names](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/WebObjects/Web_Services/How_to_Trust_Any_SSL_Certificate).  Using that SSLUtilities class:

```
SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import certificate chain into a truststore and set the following VM arguments:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="<path to truststore file>"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="<passphrase for truststore>"
```

or override the truststore at runtime like:

```
System.setproperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","<path to truststore file>")
System.setproperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","<passphrase for truststore>")
```

Keep in mind that both options will override default JVM truststore.  So if you are hitting different sites with different certs, you may want to import all of them into one truststore.